# Cloud storage upload failure when submitting ml-engine training job

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I follow the instructions here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md

I have created a bucket  for my project and uploaded the following files to `gs://<BUCKET>/data`:

- faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta
- pet_faces_train.record-*
- pet_faces_val.record-*
- pet_label_map.pbtxt

When running

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_pets_`date +%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S` \
    --runtime-version 1.9 \
    --job-dir=gs://<BUCKET>/model_dir \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.model_main \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    -- \
    --model_dir=gs://<BUCKET>/model_dir \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://<BUCKET>/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) Cloud storage upload failure. Uploaded file does not match local file: dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz. Please retry.
```

I have rerun gcloud auth login, and actually do see that there is an `object_detection-0.1.tar.gz` file in `gs://<BUCKET>/model_dir/packages/7a24fbdd5ab652ab5a0737xxxxxx/`

I am stuck here and would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I shared your pain :)

What I did was to create a folder in my bucket called dist and then uploaded all the tar.gz  files into there and used them from the bucket rather than from my local drive.

My bucket is called: tensorflow-oxford-pets.
The contents of gs://tensorflow-oxford-pets/dist are now:

- object_detection-0.1.tar.gz
- slim-0.1.tar.gz
- pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz

then instead of a local path.

- --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \

I used a bucket path:

- --packages gs://tensorflow-oxford-pets/dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,gs://tensorflow-oxford-pets/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,gs://tensorflow-oxford-pets/dist/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz \